# Why is my Array shrinking when using the Transpose function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Function that finds a column in a report, inserts a new column at that location, then does some calculations in arrays and writes those values into the new column. After my calculations are done, I have a single dimension array (pckArr) that doesn't want to write to the column so I transpose it to make it a 2d array which I can then write directly to my column. When the array is transposed, it's contents shrink considerably.

For example, my report today has 125133 rows of data. After calculations, pckArr is 'Variant(1 to 125121)' (11 less than the number of rows due to report headers we don't need). After transposing, pckArr becomes 'Variant(1 to 59585, 1 to 1)'. There's 65548 rows missing. I'm newer to coding so if there's a better way to do this please let me know, thank you!

```
Private Function AddPkgCount()

Dim myArr(), pckArr(), rowz As Double, qtyCol As Long, pckCol As Range, colPck, colQty, colSize

Call ddFunctions.FindColumn("Member ID") 'Finds and selects the column header named "Member ID"
    colPck = ActiveCell.column 'Stores the column number to a variable
'Cells(12, colPck).EntireColumn.Insert 'Insert a new column
'Cells(12, colPck).value = "# of Packages" 'Rename the column header on the new column

rowz = Range("A12").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 11 'Count number of rows, +11 for report header

ReDim myArr(2)
Call ddFunctions.FindColumn("QTY")
    colQty = ActiveCell.column
Call ddFunctions.FindColumn("PKG")
    colSize = ActiveCell.column

myArr(1) = Range(Cells(13, colQty), Cells(rowz, colQty)) 'Quantity
myArr(2) = Range(Cells(13, colSize), Cells(rowz, colSize)) 'Total Package Size

Dim i As Double
For i = 1 To UBound(myArr(1), 1)
    ReDim Preserve pckArr(1 To i)
    If myArr(2)(i, 1) = 0 Then
        pckArr(i) = 0
    Else
        pckArr(i) = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Round((myArr(1)(i, 1)) / (myArr(2)(i, 1)), 3), 0)
    End If
Next i

pckArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pckArr)

Range(Cells(13, colPck), Cells(rowz, colPck)).value = pckArr()
Range(Cells(13, colPck), Cells(rowz, colPck)).numberFormat = "0.00"
Cells(12, colPck).EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Function
```

Comment: Transpose has a limit of around 65k elements.

Comment: Declare pckArr as a 2D array and assign values to `pckArr(i,1)`